# Display path from right to left

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, slds

I want to display a field status in a very visual way, the path component is ideal (any of them, for example [lightning:path](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_path.htm) or even the [slds one](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path)):

[image]

**Problem:**

Displaying that component from right to left (trying to change the dirhtml attribute) results:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div dir="ltr">
    <lightning:picklistPath aura:id="picklistPath"
                            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                            variant="linear"
                            picklistFieldApiName="Status__c"
                            onselect="{!c.selectPathStage}"/>
</div>
```

for changing from left-to-right to right-to-left I change the `dir="ltr"` to `dir="rtl"`

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to show this path in rtl? (even a css solution would be great)
2. If not - is there any other component or visual way to show all stages and emphasize your current stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly able to scope the CSS, you should  maybe be able to apply a solution similar to [reverse the order of div's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918693/reverse-the-order-of-divs-children). Otherwise, this will require you code a custom component that fits your specific requirement.

modern browsers now support the following for reversing (mirroring) elements (using Flex):

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

I believe [SLDS](https://archive-2_3_1.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid) also has some reversing capabilities (if the child elements are in a grid) --> `slds-grid_reverse`

Comment: reversing the elements do not work on this component - direction here is within the component visually. I do not want to create my own custom component for that, I was wondering if there is a solution or maybe other visual component that can help me...

Comment: No out of the box solution to my knowledge